# UITableView Scroll Indicator in Left Side

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to bring Scroll indicator to the left side of a table view.

```
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width-8);
```

Above code is working fine for iPhone 5, 5C etc.

But scroll indicator is not positioned well in iPhone 6. It shows some padding from left side.

Comment: Where have you set scrollIndicatorInsets?

Comment: see the above code

Comment: I mean where in the code? in which method?

Comment: inside the viewDidLoad method

Comment: try setting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews method

Comment: Thanks bro.. working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` method, the bounds of the view are not set correctly and if view is set in nib/storyboard, bounds are set accroding to size of view set there.

I guess, in your nib.storyboard you have chosen iPhone 5S/iPhone 5S size to design the view and henceit works in those devices.

If you set tableView's scrollIndicatorInsets in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, the indicator inset should set correctly.